# Shouldn't all/most Deadpool-2016 questions also be tagged Deadpool?

Tags: discussion, tags

I had added [deadpool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool) to my ignored tags and life was good. Then, to my dismay, I start seeing Deadpool questions again. Turns out they were not tagged Deadpool but rather Deadpool-2016. I'm fine with adding that one to my ignored tags as well, but it got me wondering...

**Shouldn't all/most *[deadpool-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool-2016)* questions also be tagged *[deadpool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool)*?**

Comment: Very similar question, relating to a different franchise: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/should-we-add-the-star-trek-tag-to-all-of-the-star-trek-questions-that-dont-h

Comment: of note: you can ignore [tag:deadpool*]

Comment: Also, sorry about the bother, since I created the tag. But there seemed to be an increasing number of questions, some of which were very similar to each other except one was about the movie, and one about the comics. I felt we needed a clear distinction, here.

Comment: See http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/should-we-add-the-star-trek-tag-to-all-of-the-star-trek-questions-that-dont-h

Comment: @Mithrandir I already linked that one :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Remind me not post when I'm sleeping...

Comment: @Mithrandir Don't post when you're sleeping :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

The tag [deadpool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool) should be for the character / the franchise.

I know the tag [deadpool-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool-2016) reads:

> Use this tag for questions related to the 2016 Deadpool movie. Use [deadpool] for general questions about the character or the franchise.

But that's only recently, because I added that. It had general info in place of the usage guidance, so I edited it.

Since [deadpool-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool-2016) is a (large) part of the [deadpool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool) franchise, questions with the former tag should have the latter as well (ideally).

Answer (score 3):

The tag [deadpool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool) seems to about the character, and while it's not explicit, I would assume about the comic character *mainly*.

The tag [deadpool-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool-2016) says:

> Use this tag for questions related to the 2016 Deadpool movie. Use [deadpool] for general questions about the character or the franchise.

So it's possible to only ask about the movie, or not want 'general' answers about the character.

So no I don't think would be good to require *every* [deadpool-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool-2016) question to require the [deadpool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool) tag.

For instance:

[What are the names in the dead pool in Deadpool?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120618/what-are-the-names-in-the-dead-pool-in-deadpool)

Has no relation to the character himself.

In conclusion, *most* would have both, but not as a rule. Only because you'd imagine a question about his movie would involve the main guy himself.

Comment: so... you're saying that, while some might not, most will be about the movie and the character and thus should be tagged with both, ... right?

Comment: @RedCaio yes most should, not as a rule but out of course based on the question. Please take it easy on retagging so as not to swamp the front page.

Comment: I don't really re-tag things since I'm _terrible_ at tags, I apparently never know when they right or wrong. :/ But would you consider adding that clarification into your answer about  most should/would have both?

Comment: This is actually a bigger mess than just Deadpool. Take a look at [iron-man-3] for example. Some about the character also have the [iron-man] tag, some don't. Some clearly just about that film are also tagged with the character. I'm sure this will happen anytime we have character/movie tags that are essentially the same, since we don't have a solid policy on naming tags with regards to characters vs. franchise vs. titles.

Comment: In regards to my last comment, I moved my analysis of [naming conventions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9246/31178) to a new answer, along with my opinion of why it's an issue.